# Can't send a post request when the 'Content-Type' is set to 'application/json'

Tags: json, reactjs, cors, fetch, content-type

I am working on a React application and I am using fetch to send a request. I have made a Sign Up form recently and now I am integrating it with it's API. Previously the API accepted url encoded data and it was all working fine. but now that the requirement has changed and the API accepts data in JSON, I had to change the content-type header from 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' to 'application/json'. But I get the following error:

> Fetch API cannot load http://local.moberries.com/api/v1/candidate.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have even set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' in the API but it still doesn't work. Here is the relevant code for the client side:

```
sendFormData() {
    let {user} = this.props;

    var formData = {
      first_name: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.firstName).value,
      last_name: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.lastName).value,
      city: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.currentCity).value,
      country: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.currentCountry).value,
      is_willing_to_relocate: user.selectedOption,
      cities: relocateTo,
      professions: opportunity,
      skills: skills,
      languages: language,
      min_gross_salary: minSal,
      max_gross_salary: maxSal,
      email: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.email).value,
      password: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.password).value
    };

    var request = new Request('http://local.moberries.com/api/v1/candidate', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    });

    var requestBody = JSON.stringify(formData);

    console.log(requestBody);

    fetch(request, {body: requestBody})
      .then(
        function (response) {
          if (response.status == 200 || response.status == 201) {
            return response.json();
          } else {
            console.log('Failure!', response.status);
          }
        }).then(function (json) {

      var responseBody = json;

      console.log(typeof responseBody, responseBody);
    });

  }
```

And here is the relevant API code:

```
class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, application/json');
    }
}
```

I really can't figure out the problem. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://local.moberries.com/api/v1/candidate isn't accessible

Comment: Because it is local. You can't access it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It turns out that CORS only allows some specific content types.

> The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are:
>
> - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - multipart/form-data
> - text/plain

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

To set the content type to be 'application/json', I had to set a custom content type header in the API. Just removed the last header and added this one:

```
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
```

and it is working all good.

Comment: In my case, I had to change the `Content-Type` to `text/plain` in order to make it work. Adding those headers into the API response at server side didn't help. I am using IBM WAS 8559. It seems its API is not able to provide the required response headers for the `OPTIONS` method used in CORS preflighted requests.

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the '[Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)'. A website www.example.com may never be able to load resources from any website www.example.net other than from itself.

During development however, sometimes one needs to be able to do that. To bypass this:

1. either move your origin to http://local.moberries.com,
2. or move the api (which you are accessing) to your localhost.
3. Other than that, there are ways to temporarily turn off restrictions of these kinds in some browsers (esp. Chrome), methods of which usually require more and more effort in the subsequent updates of the browser. Search Google about how to turn on Cross-Origin Resource Sharing in your version of the browser.
4. Or, as the error prompt suggests, introduce a header allowing requests to be entertained from non-origins. More information is in [the documentation for Access Control CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: I disagree that you "may never" send requests to another site. It's perfectly normal to load balance by sending web requests to `www.server.com` and API requests to `api.server.com`. You just need to tell your server to set headers that inform the browser of what's allowed and what isn't, as the other answer here briefly touches on.