# XMLHttpRequest JSON Post going as form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I have a form in a HTML page which does the following:

```
form method="POST" id="myForm" onsubmit="callSlates();">
```

**Javascript function is as follows:**

```
function callSlates(){
    var form=document.getElementById('myForm');

    form.action = "https://dev1-apiservicesweb.dev.jabs.com:8111/api/v1/systems/slates";

    // collect the form data while iterating over the inputs
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0, ii = form.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        var input = form[i];
        if (input.name == "ID1") {
            data[input.name] = input.value;
        }
        if (input.name == "SDCode") {
            data[input.name] = input.value;
        }
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', form.action);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));

}
//return false;
}
```

POST calls are happening but when I check the Request Header, it shows that the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and am ending with error **504-Gateway Timeout Error**

The endpoint I am calling expects json header and JSON data. I believe I am doing that but when I used Chrome developer tools, I don't see that. Has it got something to do **with the way am making the call?**

**Edit:** When I tried hitting that URL with Postman, with header and body as JSON, am getting 200 response (as expected).

**UPDATE:** I understood that the form was getting submitted rather than the Ajax call and thus took `Barmar` advice and put `return false;` in form onsubmit. Now am not getting **504** anymore and getting **405** instead.

Following is the request header am seeing currently:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:dev1-apiservicesweb.dev.jabs.com:8111
Origin:http://localhost:3000
```

And in general information, it says:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405
```

As per `le_m`, could this be a CORS issue?

Comment: Why the `java` tag?

Comment: I posted similar question which had less audience and no response and java dev's often do ajax calls and use XMLHttpRequest object and thus added.

Comment: Can someone help me with it? Its been plaguing me for a day now.

Comment: I think more is going on than what you've presented. like a form submission. or maybe CORS.

Comment: form submission it is. It's not CORS issue as I found no issues when doing call from Postman. Can form submission cause any unwanted issues?

Comment: well, yeah, it aborts any ajax requests you have running. such as the one in your question.

Comment: Also... it working in postman has nothing to do with cors. postman isn't sending requests using ajax/xhr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142945/discussion-between-anuj-balan-and-kevin-b).

Comment: Can you suggest what's the right way to proceed from here? I want to make sure am sending the data to API endpoint and waiting for response.

Comment: What if instead of `xhr.onreadystatechange`, you tried something like `xhr.onload=function(event){ alert("The server says: " + event.target.response); };`?

Comment: What's the difference.. Sorry not that familiar with all these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your request works from your local host via postman but not from within the browser, the culprit is probably the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy):

Your browser attempts to send a [Cross Origin Request (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). There are two types of CORS requests:

- Preflighted requests: The browser first asks the server about supported HTTP methods by sending an HTTP OPTIONS request followed by the actual HTTP request upon approval.
- Simple requests: The browser directly sends the actual HTTP request.

Now, which of the above does your browser choose? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) states that simple requests will be send if the `Content-Type` is one of the following:

```
 application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 multipart/form-data
 text/plain
```

However, `Content-Type: application/json` is not allowed for simple requests. Thus, you currently send preflighted CORS requests. You can verify that by opening the developer console e.g. in Firefox: You will notice that your code first sends an OPTIONS request.

Now, this OPTIONS request receives a *405 Method not allowed* error. This indicates that the server doesn't support preflighted CORS requests. You either need to change the server configuration OR change the `Content-Type` to one of the compatible ones listed above. If your server can't accept one of those content types, then you are probably out of luck.

See also [this answer given by @ArslanTariq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39012388/1647737) in reply to a similar issue.

Comment: I believe it could be le_m. Posted more information now.

Comment: That exactly was the issue. I turned off the web security in Chrome to confirm that and even with content-type: Json, I got 200 response. I believe I need not do anything in code specially than the one I posted here. Also, I'll be moving this code to a specific server/. Going forward I may not see this issue (As it won't be localhost anymore) ?

Comment: @AnujBalan If you run this code from the same domain as your server API endpoint is on, then you should see no issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're not preventing the normal form submission. Change your form to:

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm" onsubmit="callSlates();return false;">
```

`return false;` prevents the default submit action.

There's also no need to set `form.action` in your function, since you don't want to submit the form normally.

Comment: Trying the suggestion given. You want me to remove the form.action from JS code?

Comment: Yeah, just use a normal variable.

Comment: Posted more info Barmar

Comment: It does seem like a CORS issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try the solution in the question le_m linked to?

Comment: I don't have access to endpoint API to add additional content-Type.