# can't set header with fetch

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

I set a header for post a request with application/x-www-form-urlencoded form body;
here's my code

```
var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

      fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        mode:"cors",
        header:headers,
       body: qs.stringify(params)
    })
```

But Content-type changed autoly in the request

```
Content-Type    text/plain;charset=UTF-8
```

So that I can't receive this request params correctly.
Any one meet that?

Comment: try `headers` instead of `header`, like: `fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        mode:"cors",
        headers, /...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS only allows a subset of content types. I lost lots of hours to this one. :)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39012388/4593972). Even though `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` could be possible in a CORS request, I think it's very likely that your header is being overwritten by setting `mode: 'cors'` in your `fetch` call.

Comment: yeah.I'm surely lost lots of hour to this.And Cherniv is Right .And I love you too,man!