# Does Axios support Set-Cookie? Is it possible to authenticate through Axios HTTP request?

Tags: express, cookies, axios

I'm trying to authenticate express API back-end using Axios HTTP request call. 
I was able to see 'Set-Cookie' in the response header, but cookie was not set. Is it possible to set cookies through Axios HTTP calls?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 355
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 28 Sep 2018 05:59:01 GMT
ETag: W/"163-PAMc87SVHWkdimTJca7oRw"
Set-Cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9...; Max-Age=3.6; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 28 Sep 2018 05:59:04 GMT; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Try this out!

```
axios.get('your_url', {withCredentials: true}); //for GET
axios.post('your_url', data, {withCredentials: true}); //for POST
axios.put('your_url', data, {withCredentials: true}); //for PUT
axios.delete('your_url', data, {withCredentials: true}); //for DELETE
```

For more information on this from the axios docs:

"withCredentials indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials" - https://github.com/axios/axios

More detail on withCredentials:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Comment: It works! Also I needed to add app.use(cors({ credentials: true })); on express API. I found out that Ajax requests ignore Cookies in CORS calls without credentials. Thanks @Aaron

Comment: Happy I could help!

Comment: `withCredentials` is useful only for HTTP Basic Authentication

Comment: @Begueradj `withCredentials` is also useful for sending and setting cookies.

Comment: @Aaron
With this solution, I succeeded to pass request param body with form data. But when I changed to json, it responds error showing that I was blocked by CORS policy. This is what I tried axios.post('URL', data, { withCredentials: true });

Comment: @LeeDat This might fix your problem but I’m not 100% certain. I’m thinking you’ll need to set the ‘Content-Type’ header to something CORS compliant. Check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/39012388

Comment: It works! However, one more issue I'm facing is that the cookie doesn't submit by default to my backend. I've already followed add withCredentials to attach cookie to the request.

Answer (score 35):

Yes you can set cookies by **Axios**. The cookies need to be passed into the headers object. You can send cookies in a get/post/put/delete/etc. request: 
As suggested by **Aaron:**

```
axios.get('URL', {
  withCredentials: true
}); 
axios.post('URL', data, {
withCredentials: true
}); 
axios.put('URL', data, {
withCredentials: true
});
axios.delete('URL', data, {
withCredentials: true
});
```

Or you may also try this:

```
axios.get(url, {
            headers: {
                Cookie: "cookie1=value; cookie2=value; cookie3=value;"
            }
        }).then(response => {
              console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I tried this way, but the browser keep telling me `Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"`

Comment: @kenshinji You get that error from browser because, per the XHR specification, the setRequestHeader method should not set headers with a forbidden header name.

Answer (score 14):

In case anyone else faces the problem I've had,

Here's a repost of my answer on a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62821342/8479303

---

In my case, the network panel showed that the response had the 'Set-Cookie' header, but in axios the header wouldn't show up, and the cookie was being set.

For me, the resolution was setting the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header.

For explanation, from [this comment](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2847#issuecomment-605417894) on an issue in the axios repository I was directed to this [person's notes](https://github.com/chinesedfan/You-Dont-Know-Axios#nightmares-of-headers-cors-cookies-and-auth) which led me to set the [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers) -- and now the cookie is properly setting in the client.

So, in Express.js, I had to add the `exposedHeaders` option to my cors middleware:

```
const corsOptions = {
  //To allow requests from client
  origin: [
    "http://localhost:3001",
    "http://127.0.0.1",
    "http://104.142.122.231",
  ],
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"],
};

...

app.use("/", cors(corsOptions), router);
```

---

It was also important that on the axios side I use the `withCredentials` config in following axios requests that I wanted to include the cookies.

ex/

```
const { data } = await api.get("/workouts", { withCredentials: true });
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works! everything is too old and fails.

Answer (score 6):

I tried setting `withCredentials: true` but was still getting this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4000/users/register. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

CORS was configured to allow requests from the frontend port.

I had to change the default options for axios like so:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

And the issue was solved. No error and Set-Cookie working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

cookie can't be touched, the thing is it gets bundled to request object after appended to the response object.

```
function sign(req,res){
  res.cookie("x-token", signed, { maxAge: (new JWTService().jwtExpirySeconds * 
   1000) });
}
```

client after receiving this response just have to continue with requests, set-cookie in the name of "Cookie " will be bundled to those request, like this
[image: Response header from backend]

[image: Subsequent request headers will have Cookie]

caveat: when http cookie expires its is automatically removed and not bundled to request there after.