# Axios requests using cookie to authenticate .net core User

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core, cookies, axios

I need to authenticate the user on the backend using the *authentication cookie* I have stored. I need to request API in *Vue* using *axios* requests and send cookie in those requests. The user should then be authenticated in the backend *controller*. I store the *cookie* as a whole:

```
public string GetOrchardAuthCookie()
{
    return new ChunkingCookieManager().GetRequestCookie(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext, "orchauth_Default");
}
```

my axios request:

```
axios.get(apiUrl, {
        headers: {
            "orchauth_Default": mySavedCookie
        }
    })
        .then(response =>
        {
            this.categories = response;
        })
        .catch(this.errorHandle);
```

after the request is made and I stop the code in the controller, the user has **0 claims**

**How to make Axios request to authenticate User in asp .net core controller?**

Comment: Could this case answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549079/does-axios-support-set-cookie-is-it-possible-to-authenticate-through-axios-http

Comment: @RuikaiFeng I have my Orchauth_Default cookie saved in html input element. I need to retrieve it inside widget and send it in api requests. My backend api then should automatically autenticate user. withCredentials: true has nothing to do with this, you cannot add cookie with this solution. Maybe i just do not understand correctly, feel free to explain. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The cookie had to be passed to Axios as follows:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['orchauth_Default'] = mySavedCookie;
```

my OrchardCore backend will now automatically authenticate users in the api controller