# cookie are not set in browser when I am use the node as backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, mern

Cookies are not set in browser. I am use the node as backend. I am try to search problem some person tell that's cookies will not setting because of I am using react as front and node as backed both are run on same virtual server that is localhost. That why it happen.
this is my code please help.
**User.js**

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const RegisterModel = require("../Model/RegisterModel")
const signIn = async (req,res)=>{
    try {
       const data = await RegisterModel.findOne({Email:req.body.email})
       const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,data.Password)
       const token = await jwt.sign({Email : data.Email}, process.env.SECRET)
       
       if(!data) return res.status(404).json({islogin:false, message: "User doesn't exist" })
       if(!passwordMatch) return res.status(400).json({islogin:false,message: "Incorrect Password"})
       
       if(passwordMatch){
        res.cookie('newToken',token, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: false});
        res.status(200).send({id:data._id,email:data.Email,name:data.Name,islogin:true,token:token})
        
         }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({islogin:false,message:"User doesn't exist"})
        console.log(error)
    }
}


module.exports = {signIn,signUp};
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser())
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config()

var cors = require('cors')
const PORT = process.env.PORT ;
const router = require("./Router/Router")

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(router);
require("./Connection/Connection")


app.listen(PORT,()=>{
        console.log(`Listen at Port ${PORT}` )
})
```

Comment: How do you make a request from the frontend?

Comment: using axios I'll make request for login . When login successful at time I'll generate the cookie and try to stored the browser cookie.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Axios support Set-Cookie? Is it possible to authenticate through Axios HTTP request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549079/does-axios-support-set-cookie-is-it-possible-to-authenticate-through-axios-http)

Comment: I am try this but showing new error that is

Comment: ccess to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/admin/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: but I already require the cors

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i

Comment: actually, I have copy the error and search on google

Comment: You have to configure module to use only one domain. `*` (the default) is not allowed

Comment: Then what is the solution

Comment: Can I use different method to  request from the frontend?

Comment: `cors({ origin: 'yourwebsite.com' })`

Comment: app.use(cors({ origin:'http://localhost:3000'}))

Comment: I am added this but showing same error.

Comment: Did you remove `app.use(cors())`?

Comment: Yes have removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for set credentials data into browser it is necessary to run both side on same domain backend should be run on localhost or 127.0.0.1 and frontend should be run on localhost or 127.0.0.1 **respectively**.
or

backend and frontend run on =localhost or

backend and frontend run on =127.0.0.1

if you are not sure then issue error's show on console. here

[image]

browser suggest you error regarding cookies.

also set cors policy on backend side like =

cors({origin:"http:localhost:frontendPORT", credentials:true})

frontend side on http request, must be set with credentials= true

this method work for me after spending 4 days.

Answer (score 0):

**if you are using MERN React Node
also if you are using Axios
Add the below line on the top level of react application(e.g App.js)**

```
axios.withCredentials = true
```

**on the backend

```
install cors
```

&
add the below lines**

```
import cors from "cors";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ credentials: true }));
```