# Django REST framework and Vue.js "CSRF cookie not set" is occurred

Tags: django, vue.js, authentication, cookies, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement the login feature using django and vue.js.
But I got an error "CSRF cookie not set" when sending the post request. I checked that I could get the csrftoken correctly by seeing the developer tools.

Below is the code of login.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div class="title-color">This is a Login page.</div>
    <div class="form-container">
        <form v-on:submit.prevent="getCSRF">
          <h2>Add User</h2>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label">username</label>
            <input class="input" type="text" v-model="username" /><br>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label">password</label>
            <input class="input" type="text" v-model="password" /><br>
          </div>
          <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'x-csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

export default {
  name: "LoginView",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      csrftoken: "",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
  },
  methods: {
    getCSRF() {
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/csrf/",
        auth: {
          username: "cannot show",
          password: "cannot show",
        },
      }).then((response) => {
        this.csrftoken = response.headers['x-csrftoken'];
        console.log("token is ", this.csrftoken);
        axios({
          method: "post",
          url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/",
          data: {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password,
          },
          headers: {
            'X-Csrftoken': this.csrftoken,
          },
          auth: {
            username: "Cannot show",
            password: "Cannnot show",
          },
        }).then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
      })
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Below is the views.py

```
def loginView(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        response = JsonResponse({'detail': 'OK'})
        return response
    else:
        return Response("Invalid username or password.")
    
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def getToken(request):
    response = JsonResponse({'detail': 'csrf cookie set'})
    response['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'X-Csrftoken'
    response['x-csrftoken'] = get_token(request)
    return response
```

I could set X-Csrftoken to the request headers correctly. However, I'm not sure how I can set the cookie.

Comment: It seems that axios doesn't send cookies by default. Could you try to use withCredentials=true option like pointed out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549079/does-axios-support-set-cookie-is-it-possible-to-authenticate-through-axios-http) ? Could you check the network panel of the browser window if cookies are sent back to the server?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. In login.vue, I've already added axios.defaults.withCredentials = true But it doesn't solve the problem.
I found that the cookie that I send was blocked because it had "SameSite=Lax".
I'll try to fix it and will write the update.

Comment: I added 
`response.set_cookie('key', 'value', secure=True, samesite='None')`
to the loginView. and 
`SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None`
to the setting.py (django)
But it didn't solve the problem.