# In C# WebAPI, how do I configure CORS to allow a POST request with credentials and json content?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following headers in my WebAPI web.config:

```
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://localhost:44379" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With, content-type, Accept, Origin, Authorization, User-Agent, Referer" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

When I send the following POST call in front-end, I get the errors:

"*Access to fetch at 'https://server-name/Grouping/api/Grouping/GetGroupByProcessId' from origin 'https://localhost:44379' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.*"

and

*OPTIONS https://server-name/Grouping/api/Grouping/GetGroupByProcessId 401 (Unauthorized)*

```
var headers = new Headers();

            headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.append("Accept", "application/json");

            fetch("https://<host-name>/Grouping/api/Grouping/GetGroupByProcessId", {
                method: "POST",
                 credentials: "include",
                headers: headers,
                body: JSON.stringify({ GroupingValue: groupingValue }) //groupingValue is just a JSON array
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Examining the response and request headers in the console, I see the following, and everything looks fine to me.

[image: This is what the request looks li.e]

I can't seem to figure out why I keep getting an unauthorized message.
My GET requests are going through just fine.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998684/cant-send-a-post-request-when-the-content-type-is-set-to-application-json) suggests that you *can* send JSON with a post, but I have that header for Allow-Headers and it's still not working.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See https://blogs.msmvps.com/kenlin/2018/01/18/2694/

Comment: In your `WebApiConfig.cs` file, under the `Register` method, add the following: `EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:44379", "*", "GET,POST");  config.EnableCors(cors);`

Answer (score 0):

Open the file App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs. Add the following code to the WebApiConfig.Register method:

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // New code
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Next, add the [EnableCors] attribute to the TestController class:

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://host-name.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // Controller methods not shown...
    }
}
```