# What is the reason for my POST API Route Handler failing?

Tags: javascript, post, next.js

I have tested this on a very simple case:

```
//route.ts 
export async function GET() {
 
  return new Response('Hello, Next.js!', {
    status: 200,
  })
}
```

I can call this fine via:

```
const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}generate/test`, {
method: 'GET',
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
}
```

And it returns 'Hello, Next.js!' fine.

**But if I change the same route to POST instead of GET, like:**

```
//route.ts
export async function POST() {     
  return new Response('Hello, Next.js!', {
    status: 200,
  })
}
```

And call it via:

```
const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}generate/test`, {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: "AA",
}
```

The preflight request now fails, and the request returns 405 error; so it seems that for some reason, next.js is no longer handling this route when I change it to a POST method. Is this a bug, or why is this?

Some things I have tried:

- Next.js v13 and v14, both same problem.
- Try with and without middleware.
- Confirm that response headers are correct for preflight (allowedOrigin, allowedMethods, and allowedHeaders are fine).
- Inspected to find that when I call my route, next.js says it is compiling that specific route, so it seems to recognize it but doesn't handle it for whatever reason.

I can't get POST method API Route Handler to work even in the simplest case. What could be the problem?

Comment: If you're using Next.js, the requests shouldn't be cross-origin

Comment: @Phil If I understand correctly, you mean because next.js usually serves the frontend from the same origin, right? If so, my reason for needing cross origin is I'm only using Next.js for my serverless backend. My frontend is on react native, so will be hosted on a different domain. It's a bit of a wonky setup and the only reason I got here is because I wanted to use this: https://github.com/awinogrodzki/next-firebase-auth-edge
With vercel edge runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In that case, you'll want to enable CORS support. See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-cors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJs CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058598/nextjs-cors-issue)

Comment: I think route handlers have a different CORS setup than pages/API routes. It's been a while, but I setup a middleware for the project for my CORS setup, I think this [https://codingwithmanny.medium.com/3-ways-to-configure-cors-for-nextjs-13-app-router-api-route-handlers-427e10929818](blog post) mentions it at the end. Looking in the network tab in the browser, I think it is working fine and the headers are responded correctly. But I'm stumped as to why GET works but POST does not, [https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#supported-http-methods](docs).

Comment: Your GET is a simple request, requiring no preflight OPTIONS request. Your POST request is non-simple due to the content-type header value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39012388/283366)

Comment: Oh! I did not know that. Now this makes a lot more sense, thank you. I will try and see if one of these methods work.

Comment: Ah, sorry about linking to API Routes info. There's a discussion here about CORS in Route Handlers ~ https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/47933

Comment: Here are my response headers:
`access-control-allow-credentials
 true
access-control-allow-headers
 Content-Type, Authorization
access-control-allow-methods
 POST,GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin
 http://localhost:19006
Connection
 keep-alive
Date
 Tue, 31 Oct 2023 03:30:55 GMT
Keep-Alive
 timeout=5
Transfer-Encoding
 chunked
vary
 RSC, Next-Router-State-Tree, Next-Router-Prefetch, Next-Url`

I hoped the problem/solution was setting the content type as you mentioned, but it still has the same problem. I will look into it again to be sure.

Comment: Yep, there's more to CORS than just response headers. You also need to handle preflight requests

Comment: Give a thumbs up on this issue which calls out how bad the docs are https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/50171

Comment: It finally works! So, the problem was that I was not returning the OPTIONS requests in the middleware early, so they would go and try to find a matching route which I did not define. I got stuck since the GET request was working, but as you pointed out my misunderstanding I could finally make progress figuring it out. Thank you very much for leading me to a solution here, much appreicated :).

Comment: If the duplicate I linked doesn't answer your question, feel free to post your own solution below. I'm sure it will help others in the future

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I'm using:

In middleware.ts:

```
export const corsHeaders = {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:19006",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
};


export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const response = NextResponse.next()

  // Need to handle OPTIONS request here, unless you want to not use middleware
  // In which case you can define the OPTIONS method and set the CORS headers within route.ts
  // But using middleware is nice to avoid boilerplate of setting CORS on each route
  if (request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return NextResponse.json({}, {headers: corsHeaders})
  }

  // Then here set the CORS headers that will be returned with the regular response
  response.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", corsHeaders['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'])
  response.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", corsHeaders['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'])
  response.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", corsHeaders['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'])
  
  // Continue to eventually call the matching route.ts method
  return response;
}
```

The notable issues that were confusing were: GET and POST request are dealt with differently with CORS, so my testing was flawed. And you must set the CORS headers on both the OPTIONS request (and return early, if not defining OPTIONS in each route.ts) as well for the normal requests. Thanks to phil for helping me figure it out.